# Convert List to integer in Python

Tags: python, list

In Python, I want to convert list into int.

so if i have input like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

i want this output:

```
1234
```

so How it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `join` function in conjunction with a generator, like this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

int(''.join(str(i) for i in a))
```

Output:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

With recursion:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
def f(l):
    if not l: return 0
    return l[-1] + f(l[:-1]) * 10
print(f(a))
```

This outputs:

```
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator comprehension in the following way:
`result = int(''.join((str(i) for i in a)))`

This turns every item of the list to a string, joins the list together and then turns the whole thing back to an integer